Python telegram-api-bot inline buttons
Подскажите и наведите на путь истинный! У меня проблема с использованием inline кнопок, необходимо создать кнопку при нажатии которой, запускался бы процесс: с последнего отправленного сообщения, из tags выбирались 3 рандомных тега, и, пока-что, только выводились в консоль. Не могу понять как мне перенести данные tags в обработчик:
bot.message_handler(commands=["random"])
def random_post(message):

keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

random_num = random.randint()
url = f""
print(f"Ссылка - {url}")

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        
        if data:                
            file = data[0] 
            
            tags = file.get("tags").split(" ")
            print(f"Теги - {tags}")                
            
            #получение информации о имени файла
            file_url = file.get("file_url")
            #получение информации о типе файла спомощью сплита
            file_extension = file_url.split(".")[-1].lower()

            #Создание кнопки для поиска изображение с похожими тегами 
            keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            
            button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Найти похожее изображение", callback_data = f"tag_button:{",".join(tags)}")#tag_button для call ф button для markup
            print(f"ДАННЫЕ ЗАНЕСЕНЫ В КНОПКУ {tags}\n") 
            button2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Открыть в браузере", url = file_url)
           
            #определение файла то есть понимание какой тип файла в имени и отправка 
            if file_extension in ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"]:
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file_url, caption=f"Код - {random_num}", reply_markup = keyboard)
            elif file_extension in ["webm", "mp4", "gif"]:
                bot.send_video(message.chat.id, file_url, caption=f"Код - {random_num}", reply_markup = keyboard)
                
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Формат файла не поддерживается: {file_extension}")
                print(f"ОШИБКА!!! ФОРМАТ ФАЙЛА НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТСЯ!!! КОД НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ЕГО ТИП {file_extension}")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Нет данных для отправки.")
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ошибка при получении данных: {response.status_code}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка при выполнении запроса: {e}")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Произошла ошибка при выполнении запроса.")


bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: call.data.startswith("tag_button"))
def handle_tag_button_callback(callback_query):

print(F"ПОЛУЧЕНО К ОБРАБОТКЕ{tags}\n")

tags = callback_query.data.split(':')[1].split(',')

print(f"2ПОЛУЧЕНО К ОБРАБОТКЕ{tags}\n")   

bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, tags)

bot.infinity_polling()


Сейчас просто код не выполнятся или выводит ошибку?

Я покопался в коде и нашел ошибку в ограничении на вывод символов. Т.е tags я научился переноить в обработчик но этот вариант слишком топорный. На данный момент, проблема остается той же, как перенести tags в обработчик и работать с его данными в нем.
